# Sitecore: Change context menu for items under specific item?

Tags: .net, sitecore, sitecore6

I would like to have a custom context menu (right click) for items under a specific item. I have a *folder* template (named differently ofcourse) of which on all instances of this template I would like to have a custom context menu.

I copied the `Default` context menu in de *core* database and changed some of the items under it.

- Sitecore

  - Content

    - Applications

      - Content Editor

        - Context Menues

          - Default
          - Copy of Default

I've selected this item ("Copy of Default") at several places under Appearance\Context Menu however this doesn't work...:

- *folder* template
- *folder* template standard values
- *folder* instance

**How do I *use* my custom context menu of specific items in the content editor?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been reported as a bug with Sitecore. A quick look at the code and it looks like its looking into the context db (master database) for the custom context menu instead of core where the menu lives. When it's not found then it uses the default. I haven't tried this but try copying your custom menu to somewhere in the master database and then pointing to this item - you may have to switch to raw values and paste the ID in directly as the field options are all coming from the core db. Otherwise you'll have to override the code behind of the content editor itself.

Comment: Do you have a link to the bug report, or any information on where in the source-code the bug exists?

Comment: The bug is in the code beside for the content editor application found in /sitecore/shell/Applications/Content Manager/Default.aspx  I haven't tested this on a recent version however I can't seen any mention of a fix in the release notes so presumably the bug still exists.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this is still a bug as of Sitecore 6.5 (rev 110602)

After digging into the decompilation a bit, I can see that the problem arises from the fact that the Content Editor tries to pull the Context Menu from the ContentDatabase instead of from the Core Database (where it gets the Default menu from).

To work around this, do the following:

1. Create your context menu in Core
2. Set the context menu on your item (either __Standard Values, or individual items)
3. In Core, right click your Context Menu root, click transfer, and then follow the prompts to put the context menu in the content database (master most likely)
4. Feel free to maneuver the context menu in the ContentDatabase. I put mine in /sitecore/System/Context Menus
5. That should be it. Just edit the one in the ContentDatabase instead of Core